# How do I bind a database field to an HTML TITLE element in ASP.NET 2.0?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, rendering

I know how to do this in MVC:

```
<title> <%= Model.Title %> </title>
```

I also know how to bind a SQLDataSource or ObjectDataSource to a control on a form or listview.

But how do I render a field from my SQLDataSource or ObjectDataSource directly into the HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Page.Title` property to set the title in code behind.

Once you've run your SelectCommand or equivalent on your data source, just simply assign Page.Title a value from the result set.

Alternately, you can use the aspx page itself, and just inside the html assign a text string, like this:

```
<title>
  <%= dataSource.Select(...) %>
</title>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a property and set its value using your desired field's value.

Code-behind:

```
private string myTitle;
protected string MyTitle
{
   get { return myTitle; }
   set { myTitle = value; }
}
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyTitle = "Testing 123!";
}
```

Markup: `<title><%= MyTitle %></title>`

Answer (score 1):

In WebForms you still need to use a WebControl that implements DataBinding as the "container" for your fields. For instance, a GridView, Repeater, ListView, FormView or DetailsView. Unfortunately there isn't a WebControl designed specifically for rending just one row or object. So, you have a choice:

Use a Repeater something like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="MyDataSource">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Eval("MyProperty") %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Another alernative is to not use a DataSource. Instead, add properties to your page and then bind your data to these. For example, in your page codebehind:

```
public string MyPageProperty 
{
    get { return _myPageProperty; }
    set { _myPageProperty = value; }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MyPageProperty = "This is some data";
}
```

You can then do this in your page:

```
<div>The value is: <%= MyPageProperty %></div>
```

Hope that helps.