# can ASP.net websites share some of the code on same server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Right now i have 7 websites and the number may increase. every time i copy code of a website and change title etc to create new website. All these sites have same code in app_code folder and in some of the folders for code behind files of aspx files. The code is on same dedicated server for all the websites. **Can these websites share the code, so that if i make a change to the code it is reflected on all the websites?** Presently it needs me to make change to all the websites.

Regards
Aijaz

Comment: did you tried searching for "adding your assembly in the GAC"?

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what [class libraries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d11h6832%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) are for. Put all your common code into a DLL and deploy it to the [GAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173099.aspx) so it can be shared across all your sites.

Comment: can i add (1) appcode classes (2) code behind files of pages to gac and access them from pages of different sites

Comment: @syedaijaz yes & yes - they are effectively just .cs files.

Comment: can you please give me a reference link where i can have an understanding of the basics of this concept.....

Comment: @syedaijaz I would [start here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668164(VS.100).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As I guess the `Host Name` will be different for each website. So you can use `global.asax` file to set the page name (after checking the host name).

You can create a xml file or maintain it into database and on `page load` you can set the title of the page

Here is a link

[How do I bind a database field to an HTML TITLE element in ASP.NET 2.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150520/how-do-i-bind-a-database-field-to-an-html-title-element-in-asp-net-2-0)